# Is it possible to create a NavLink like structure in React using only HTML5 and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a question for you, is it possible to create a NavLink like structure in React using only HTML5 and JavaScript?

For example, if we have a homepage.html and a content.html file and I want to go to content.html when an **"a"** element is clicked, how can I do this without refreshing the page?

Comment: React Router can help you achieve this easily, which will allow you to navigate between components of your react app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can do it using the history API, you can navigate to different pages without refreshing the page

```
window.history.pushState('page 2, "page 2 title", "page2.html")
```

Incase of replace the page you can use `window.history.replaceState()` to replace the current page with the new page.

Reference:- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API

Comment: seems odd one would do this in a React App

Comment: You can use React Router to handle these things for you..